# call a script with the current value of a <textarea> when the user pushes submit?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

i'm making a html document with a simple form on it, when the user presses submit i want to call a function that takes the value of the textarea field and does some magic on it, i've had a search on w3schools and done some google digging but i just can't find anything!

**update**: i want them to be able to enter information over and over again, basically i'm taking what they enter, changing the formatting, adding some things .etc and writing it to the page, then i want to clear the textarea all fresh again.

Comment: Can you show some code, so we can help you do some magic on it? :)

Comment: Using regular javascript or any library?

Comment: who need libraries for that? anyway, changing requirements on the fly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function magic(){
        var textArea =document.forms[0].elements['myText'];
        textArea.style.color = 'red';
        alert(textArea.value)
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <textarea name="myText"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="button" onclick="magic()" value="Go"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, this bit of code should give you an idea of how you can grab the value of an input element and then manipulate it using js. I hope this is helpful :)

Comment: thanks, that worked! also i found this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html#access which says i should be able to use the names of the fields to access them instead of the array, but that doesnt work for me! `var userText=document.featureinput.featuretext.value;` is what i am using but it doesnt seem to work!

Comment: no problem :) try: `var userText = document.forms["featureinput"].elements["featuretext"].value;`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function ( event ) {
    return !!prompt( this.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value );
}
```